# Постраничная навигация как решить проблему

Tags: php

Вопрос: Постраничная навигация работает, но при переходе по ней, например на стр. 2, то пишет:

> Not Found The requested URL /book/page was not found on this server.

```
include "set.php";  
$num = 5;  

$page = $_GET['page'];  

$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM products");  
$posts = mysql_result($result, 0);  

$total = intval(($posts - 1) / $num) + 1;  

$page = intval($page);  

if(empty($page) or $page < 0) $page = 1;  
if($page > $total) $page = $total;  

$start = $page * $num - $num;  

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products LIMIT $start, $num");  

while ( $postrow[] = mysql_fetch_array($result))  
  echo "<table>";  

for($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++)  
{  
    echo "<tr> 
        <td>".$postrow[$i]['title']."</td> 
        <td>".$postrow[$i]['price']."</td></tr>";  
}  
echo "</table>";  

if ($page != 1) $pervpage = '<a href= ./page?page=1><<</a>  
           <a href= ./page?page='. ($page - 1) .'><</a> ';  

if ($page != $total) $nextpage = ' <a href= ./page?page='. ($page + 1) .'>></a>  
                   <a href= ./page?page=' .$total. '>>></a>';  

if($page - 2 > 0) $page2left = ' <a href= ./page?page='. ($page - 2) .'>'. ($page - 2) .'</a> | ';  
if($page - 1 > 0) $page1left = '<a href= ./page?page='. ($page - 1) .'>'. ($page - 1) .'</a> | ';  
if($page + 2 <= $total) $page2right = ' | <a href= ./page?page='. ($page + 2) .'>'. ($page + 2) .'</a>';  
if($page + 1 <= $total) $page1right = ' | <a href= ./page?page='. ($page + 1) .'>'. ($page + 1) .'</a>'; 

echo $pervpage.$page2left.$page1left.'<b>'.$page.'</b>'.$page1right.$page2right.$nextpage;
```

Comment: сообщение Ваше крайне смахивает на 404-ую ошибку apache. Приведите на всякий случай код .htaccess файла и подскажите адрес первой страницы.

Answer (score -2):

Изначально тяжело разобраться в вашем письме. И сам вывод пагинации порекомендовал вам переоформить. Вот набросал быстро

```
<?
    for ($i = 1; $i< $total; $i++) {
        if ($i == $page) {
?>
<span class="page_active"><?=$i?></span>
<?
    } else {
        echo "<a href='./page?=$i/'>$i</a>";
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: Не мог не удержаться, если пишите ответ, то хоть как то соблюдайте форматирование и какиенибудь нормы написания кода к примеру `<?` лучше заменить на `<?php` , `while` на `for` заменить, поправить отступы что бы ни чего не узжало. И развернуть `if` с `else` и убрать `echo`.